# Selective diff in bash

Tags: bash, diff

I want to compare two files with `diff`, but I want to skip some lines. The lines that I want to skip are marked as comments, but *only in the first file*.

For easy copy/paste testing, I write the `diff` command with [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
$ diff -y <(echo -e "aaa\nbbb\n#ccc\nddd") <(echo -e "AAAAAA\nbbb\nccc\nddd")
aaa                           | AAAAAA
bbb                             bbb
#ccc                          | ccc
ddd                             ddd
$
```

As can be seen both first line and third line is marked as a diff( `|` ). I do not want third line in the diff because of the `#` sign. I can ignore matching lines with the `-I` option, but that requires that both files match the pattern.

```
$ diff -y -I "#.*" <(echo -e "aaa\nbbb\n#ccc\nddd\n#eee") <(echo -e "AAAAAA\nbbb\nccc\nddd\n#EEEE")
aaa                           | AAAAAA
bbb                             bbb
#ccc                          | ccc
ddd                             ddd
#eee                            #EEEE
$
```

Is there a way to ignore lines based on only the first file?

**Edit:**
I forgot to write that I need the return value(`echo $?`) of `diff` to tell me if there are any non-matching lines (excluding the ones that I do not want to check).

Comment: Do your files always have a line-for-line mapping? Or could one file have extra lines?

Comment: maybe you could add `| grep -v "#" ` at the end of the command. and it would remove the "#" line

Comment: Do you need what `diff` does here (collection of groups of changed lines and shifting of lines to match earlier/later content)? Or do you just need a line-wise "diff"? If you just need line-wise "diff" output then you can use `awk` for this, etc.

Comment: @ams: My files has the same number of lines, and I  want the diff line by line.

Comment: @ClaudioM: That could remove the line from the first file, but I also need to remove the same line from the second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `grep -vE "^#"` to filter the results, and to get a meaningful return value you can use `wc -l` to count the non-common-lines;

```
A=$(diff -y --suppress-common-lines <(echo -e "aaa\nbbb\n#ccc\nddd\neee") <(echo -e "AAAAAA\nbbb\nccc\nddd\n#EEEE") | grep -vE "^#" );
echo "$A";
return $(echo "$A" | wc -l);
```

output;

```
aaa                           | AAAAAA
eee                           | #EEEE
```

return value;

```
2
```

If you want to use this example directly in a script instead of in a function use `exit` instead of `return` or `if [ $(echo "$A" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]` instead of `if [ $? -gt 0 ]`

Comment: This is almost, what I want (only `grep -e` option for pattern works in my mac bash) except that I forgot to write that I need the return value of diff.

Comment: This only works called as a script (it can not be copied directly to the bash). -but I guess that not everything is possible without getting into long unmanageable expressions with functions and `tee`s and more.

Comment: I use mac bash terminal. I get the error `bash: return: can only return from a function or sourced script`. -which makes sense - you can not return without being in a function/script.

Comment: To make `if...`
 work directly you need to add `; then true; fi`.

Comment: Your code is making a test `-gt` but it is not valid code. I will not respond to this post anymore, as it is taking form where it is not useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly what you want to do, you could simply not use `diff` at all. Since you mention in the comments that your files match in their number of lines and you want to compare the lines pairwise, you could do something like this:

```
exec 3<file1 4<file2
while read line1 <&3 && read line2 <&4; do
    if [ "$line1" != "$line2" -a -n "${line1%%#*}" ]; then
        echo "$line1 | $line2"
    fi
done
exec 3<&- 4<&-
```

I'm also pretty sure this works in any POSIX-compatible shell, rather than just bash.

Comment: This is great, but I forgot to write that I need the return value of diff.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: You could simply change the value of a variable when the `while` loop detects a differing line and use that in place of the return value of `diff`.

Comment: This is less robust than using diff, as diff will cleanly warn about non text files etc. Also if you are doing this on many huge files it will be slower.

Comment: @user1133275: It is slower, true, but to the extent that it matches OP's intention I'd argue it more robust rather than less, since it actually does what was intended, rather than `diff` that does kinda-sorta the same thing, incidentally.